# How to get rid of "call is the same expression as the source" warning in C?

Tags: c, string, arguments

I would like to copy the argument strings into an array in the program. So I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // go through each string in argv
    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc){
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        i++;
    }

    //let's make our own array of strings
    char *states[] = {"California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas"};
    int num_states = 4;
    i = 0;  //watch for this
    while(i < num_states) {
        printf("state %d: %s\n", i, states[i]);
        i++;
    }

    //copy argv into strings
    char **dst;
    dst = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*argc);
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        dst[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(argv[i]));
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < argc){
        strncpy(*dst+i, argv[i], sizeof(argv[i]));
        printf("*dst = %s\n", *dst+i);
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        free(dst[i]);
    }
    free(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine. But there is a compilation warning:

```
cc -Wall -g -o ex11 ex11.c
ex11.c: In function ‘main’:
ex11.c:31:34: warning: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘strncpy’ call is the same expression as the source; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
   strncpy(*dst+i, argv[i], sizeof(argv[i]));
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Update 1: 
I changed the allocation of the dst pointer into the following:

```
  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    //dst[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(argv[i]));
    dst[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i]+1));
  }
  // ignore malloc null return
  printf("test 1 = %d\n", sizeof(char)*sizeof(argv[i]));
  printf("test 2 = %d\n", strlen(argv[i]));
```

I want to know if test 1 and test 2 will generate the same number. But for test 2, it is complaining about segmentation fault. Why is that?

Update 2: Get rid of the malloc loop based on the comment:

```
  //copy argv into strings
  char **dst;
  dst = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*argc);

  i = 0;
  while(i < argc){
    dst[i] = strdup(argv[i]);   //array version: strdup
    printf("*dst = %s\n", *(dst+i));
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: a few problems to note: 1) the code should check the returned value from malloc to assure operation successful.  2) this line: dst[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(argv[i])); the 'sizeof[..]' should be 'strlen(argv[i])+1'  BTW: as written, the code contains undefined behaviour, because the malloc only allocates 4 bytes per entry, which can/will lead to a seg fault event when the string pointed to by argv[i] is greater than 4 characters

Comment: @user3629249: You're two hours late pointing out those problems, and wrong about the undefined behavior.  Right now the code allocates and copies the same number of characters -- `sizeof (char*)`.  There is undefined behavior for a different reason, though, in that the second group of four characters gets placed off the end of the first allocation.  But you said "when the string pointed to is greater than 4 characters" and that is completely wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler is right, and telling you about a dangerous bug.  You're using the size of a pointer, not the size of the string it points to.  (The actual warning is saying you are specifying the length to copy based on the source, making `strcpy` act like `strncpy`.  In this case it is wrong, though, because it didn't notice it is sizeof a pointer and not an array.)

You also had a serious error with `*dst+i`, which is the same as `dst[0] + i`, not `dst[i]`.  You've got `i` independently allocated pointers, best to use them all.

You should instead use

```
dst[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1); // remember space for the NUL character
```

and

```
strcpy(dst[i], argv[i]);
```

or better yet, just

```
dst[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

which does the allocation and copy both.

Comment: @ikegami: This IS what to change them to.  The "old" versions should be easy to find, there's only one line doing a `malloc`, and only one copying a string.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have a new problem after I update the code based on your comments. Could you tell me what has happened?

Comment: why is strdup better than strcpy in your example?

Comment: @dannycrane because it does both the allocation and copy, as he said

Comment: You mean i can get rid of the for loop with malloc?     dst[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[i]+1));

Comment: @dannycrane: You can replace the malloc loop and the strcpy loop with just one loop doing strdup, yes.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly without introducing more bugs. I remove the loops and use strdup in the update 2 in my post. Is that correct? Also, why there is a segmentation fault in update 1?

Comment: @dannycrane: Your update 1 uses `i` outside the loop where `i` is valid.  At the time you call printf, `i < argc` is false (which is why the loop ended), and `argv[i]` does not exist.  A second problem with update 1 is that you typed `strlen(argv[i] + 1)` but it should be `strlen(argv[i]) + 1`.  And yes, your update 2 is correct, though a `for` loop looks better for this.

Comment: Yes, a common mistake...Thank you!

Comment: one last question: in update 1: why this line always print out value 8 regardless of my argument string length? printf("test 1 = %lu\n", sizeof(char)*sizeof(argv[i]));

Comment: @dannycrane: I already told you that, so read my answer more carefully.

Comment: but if I do :     printf("test 1 = %lu\n", sizeof(char)*sizeof(*argv[i])); it always prints out value 1

Comment: @dannycrane: Yes.... the data type of `argv[i]` is `char*`, and `*argv[i]` is `char`.  So you are doing `sizeof (char) * sizeof (char*)` and then `sizeof (char) * sizeof (char)`.  Neither of which are even a little bit useful.